# Date value between in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do an update only if the date is between two dates with the next sentence:

```
db.periodo.update(
               {"id_linea" : id_linea, "id_contexto" : id_contexto,$min:   { "fecha_hora_inicio": fecha_desde }, $max:    {"fecha_hora_inicio": fecha_hasta} },
               { $set: { "id_fase": id_fase } },
               { multi: true }
            )
```

My first problem is that my structure is :

```
id_linea
id_contexto
periodo 
  id_fase 
  fecha_hora_inicio
```

If I want to use as conditions the date inside `periodo` is it enough to put "`fecha_hora_inicio`" or must I reference with `periodos.fecha_hora_inicio`?

When I tried the two sentences I get the following failure:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $min",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

I have redone my consult because i find mistake: now my consult is:

```
       db.collection.update(
               {"id_linea" : id_linea, "id_contexto" : id_contexto }, { $min: { "periodos.fecha_hora_inicio": fecha_desde }} , {$max: {"periodos.fecha_hora_inicio": fecha_hasta}} ,
               { $set: { "id_fase": id_fase }},
               { multi: true })

 }
```

When i tried in robomongo with values, for example:

```
   db.grupo_periodo.find(
               {"id_linea" : 145, "id_contexto" : 151 }, { $min: {  "periodos.fecha_hora_inicio": 2015-04-16 16:51:34  }} , {$max: {"periodos.fecha_hora_inicio": 2015-04-27 16:51:34 }}        
 }
```

i find the Error: Line 3: Unexpected number

Comment: You will have to use `periodos.fecha_hora_inicio`

Comment: thanks, now the second problem is avoid the error

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `:` after `"id_contexto"`

Comment: in my code is put the : perhaps at edit dissappears the :

Comment: `$min` is used for [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and not update

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ `$min` also used in updated check this 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/min/

Comment: thaths the problem... and something similar for updated?

Comment: @Deckard27 your update query syntax was wrong check http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/min/

Comment: i know that i have a bad consult, is my first day with mongo db... ty for all

Comment: thanks @yogesh now i have a well consult i supoose

Comment: ok, the failure is that in the database fecha is a string, i supose that try to do a min in a string is a bad thing. Ty for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some major edits after my first answer.

The structure of your document in the `grupo_periodo` collection is as follows:

```
{
  id_linea: 145,
  id_contexto: 151,
  periodo: [
    {
      fecha_hora_inicio: new Date(2014, 10, 10),
      id_fase: 'f'
    },
    {
      fecha_hora_inicio: new Date(2014, 9, 10),
      id_fase: 'f'
    }
  ]
}
```

And you want to update the "id_fase" of the "periodo" objects matching some date range.

What you are looking for is called ["positional $ update"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Here is a complete example to understand how this work:

```
db.grupo_periodo.insert({
  id_linea: 145,
  id_contexto: 151,
  periodo: [
    {
      fecha_hora_inicio: new Date(2014, 10, 10),
      id_fase: 'f'
    },
    {
      fecha_hora_inicio: new Date(2014, 9, 10),
      id_fase: 'f'
    }
  ]
});

db.grupo_periodo.insert({
  id_linea: 145,
  id_contexto: 151,
  id_fase: 'f',
  periodo: [
    {
      fecha_hora_inicio: new Date(2014, 10, 10),
      id_fase: 'f'
    },
    {
      fecha_hora_inicio: new Date(2014, 6, 10),
      id_fase: 'f'
    }
  ]
});

db.grupo_periodo.insert({
  id_linea: 145,
  id_contexto: 151,
  id_fase: 'f',
  periodo: [
    {
      fecha_hora_inicio: new Date(2014, 6, 10),
      id_fase: 'f'
    }
  ]
});

var query = {
  id_linea: 145,
  id_contexto: 151,
  'periodo.fecha_hora_inicio': {
    $gt: new Date(2014, 6, 1),
    $lt: new Date(2014, 6, 30)
  }
};

//let's update all "periodo" elements in the arrays matching the query:

db.grupo_periodo.update(query, {
  $set: {
    'periodo.$.id_fase': 'updated'
  }
}, {
  multi: true
});

//now query:
db.grupo_periodo.find(query)
```

The result of the last query is:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5538f5dacae6e0da9298ec4b"),
  "id_linea" : 145,
  "id_contexto" : 151,
  "id_fase" : "f",
  "periodo" : [
    {
      "fecha_hora_inicio" : ISODate("2014-11-10T03:00:00Z"),
      "id_fase" : "updated"
    },
    {
      "fecha_hora_inicio" : ISODate("2014-07-10T03:00:00Z"),
      "id_fase" : "f"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5538f5dbcae6e0da9298ec4c"),
  "id_linea" : 145,
  "id_contexto" : 151,
  "id_fase" : "f",
  "periodo" : [
    {
      "fecha_hora_inicio" : ISODate("2014-07-10T03:00:00Z"),
      "id_fase" : "updated"
    }
  ]
}
```

Showing that the specific `periodo` documents have the `id_fase` updated.

Comment: With an array dont work. because he can differenciate between arrays.... id_fase is in the array... thats the problem.

Comment: id_fase it is not on the array according on his description in the question. I just added a complete example, let me know if id_fase is in the array and I will update the example accordingly

Comment: Yes, i mistake in the description sry. Id_fase in inside the array.

Comment: @Deckard27 and you want to update the 'id_fase' of the matching elements in the array right?

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: if(collection !=null){

    db.collection.update(
       {"id_linea" : id_linea, "id_contexto" : id_contexto , periodos: { $elemMatch: { "fecha_hora_inicio": { $lte: fecha_hasta }, fecha_hora_fin: { $gt: fecha_desde } }}}  ,
       { $set: { "periodos.$.id_fase": id_fase }},
       { multi: true })

  }  with this all is correct now. Ty for all.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(collection !=null){

      db.collection.update(
               {"id_linea" : id_linea, "id_contexto" : id_contexto , periodos: { $elemMatch: { "fecha_hora_inicio": { $lte: fecha_hasta }, fecha_hora_fin: { $gt: fecha_desde } }}}  ,
               { $set: { "periodos.$.id_fase": id_fase }},
               { multi: true })

 }
```

With this all is perfect now.